# Zabbix & Teltonika SMS Gateway

Tags: zabbix, teltonika

I would like to utilise the Teltonika SMS Gateway in Zabbix to send SMS. The format is the following:

http://10.3.1.7/cgi-bin/sms_send?username=user1&password=user_pass&number=0037060000001&text=testmessage

I understand how to pass the variables into the script, but i'm a little unsure writing the script. Happy to be pointed in the direction where i can research to solve the issue and not just have the anwser.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the [webhook](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/notifications/media/webhook) documentation: define the url and the params, then you can use them in the javascript call.

A simple example can be found [here](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/notifications/media/webhook/webhook_examples)